# C++ Library to plot points and save as image

Tags: library, c++, plotting

I have a project I was asked to work on where a person can draw shapes. as the person draws, it records x,y coordinates and saves them in a text file. My job is to find a library for C++ in QT creator or maybe visual studios in windows 10 and be able to connect the points to show the shape they drew and save the it as an image to the pc.

So assume I drew curvy lines like in this picture below

[image: drawing]

and the text file will be something similar to this

[-5.324, 7.444]
[-5.322, 7.342]
......

I need to read in those x,y points, and generate a picture and save it as an image to show what was drawn (like the pic I posted). Now i have read library to do one or the other, but not both...

any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Di you have to use C++ - this is so easy in python.

Comment: OP here, sadly, yes, it has to be in c++